# Database mySQL query to sort last ten values from oldest to newest with TIMESTAMP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a table in a mySQL database to which I want to sort the data in this way: the last 10 values of the temperature and time sorted by time order from oldest to newest.
The field in the table is called timeStamp and is of type TIMESTAMP
like this 2016-02-10 22:41:23
Doing this query

```
SELECT * FROM `tempLog` ORDER BY` timeStamp` DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

I get the records in chronological order from most recent to oldest, but I want from oldest to newest and then put everything in a line graph

Comment: Change `DESC` to `ASC`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the last ten records sorted that way you could do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM `tempLog` ORDER BY `time_stamp` DESC LIMIT 10) AS `foo`
ORDER BY `time_stamp` ASC;
```

Comment: I get this error #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: I added an alias @MassimoMezzina